# How to extract username from command as a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a script for running USMT scanstate and then another for loadstate we are getting ready to get a bunch of computers to replace the oldest ones on the network.
I am wanting to use this script/batch/code in PDQ Deploy so I can make a list of the computers we are replacing, and then run the pdq package against them just before I go to swap them out that way all their stuff is backed up as recently as possible, and running on all the machines at once as opposed to going to each one individually. I can't do %username% as it would just return the data for the PDQ account running the command, and I can't set it to run as logged on user as they would not have sufficient privileges to run the necessary commands

I've tried tinkering with using Tokens and Delims, but nothing I try seems to work, I am sure I am getting syntax wrong.

I am using this command, though not opposed to a different command that could yield same results:

```
query user /server:%computername%
```

It outputs this (username changed to "***"):

> ```
> USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
> ***                   console            1   Active  none       7/11/2019 6:22 PM
> ```

I would like to get what is under the USERNAME part as a variable.

I am thinking like using a FOR /F command, something like:

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('net user "%Username%" /domain ^| find /i "Full Name"') do set DisplayName=%%b
```

Of course though that gives me their name instead of user name.

Comment: How is the user name separated from the session name? by _spaces_ or by _tabs_? is the output of the `query` command line of fixed width? you might notice that it is not that trivial to extract the user name here, particularly when it contains _spaces_ on its own (which is not recommended but possible, I think); so I would check whether `query` supports other output formats, which makes it easier to extract the user name...

Comment: I just found out that spaces *are* allowed in user names; consult this article: [Creating User and Group Acounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx).

Comment: This may be of interest. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LoggedOnUser-Gathers-7cbe93ea There is a comment on the Q/A tab about handling a SPACE character in the username. However, it appears to only handle one (1) SPACE character. It does not look like it would handle two (2) consecutive SPACE characters in a username. Of course, I do not know why anyone would put even one (1) SPACE character in a username.

Comment: @W_5678 - Do any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Qwinsta will also give you the username of the user on the console

```
 @(
   SetLocal
   Echo Off
 )

 FOR /F "Tokens=2" %%A IN ('
   QWinSta ^|Find /I "Console"
 ')  Do (
   SET "_UN=%%A"
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in (`query user /server:%computername%`) do set "uname=%%a"
echo User=%uname%
```

Should get the desired results if I've scried your question correctly.

The query to be run inside single-inverted-commas, read each line of output from `query...` abd the first token is assigned to `%%a` by `for` and then assigned to the variable `uname` by the `set`, so the last line of output is the one used to deliver the result. If you were to use `delims=v"` then token1 is the string up to the first `v`, disregarding any leading `v`s on the line.

This code uses the default "tokens=`and`delims`as the standard separator-character set, of which <kbd>space</kbd> is a member. You could use`"tokens=1 delims= "`for the same result, the first token in the line is required, where the delimiter used is just the space character.

If you wanted to extract `console` then `tokens=2` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A list of users on the system can be produced by:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_SystemUsers).PartComponent.name
```

If it must run from cmd.exe:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_SystemUsers).PartComponent.Name"') DO (
        ECHO user is %%A
    )
```